# Only show part of logfile in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script, bash-scripting, string-manipulation

OpenVPN log looks like this:

```
OpenVPN

CLIENT LIST
Updated,Sat Jun 20 04:20:07 2015
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
[ A .... ]
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
[ B.... ]
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,33
END
```

Where **A** and **B** above are lists of hosts formatted in a certain way.

I have a bash script that I will use to act on the items in the part called "ROUTING TABLE" (**B**). How can I separate this list of hosts from the rest of the document in an efficient manner in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used **sed** to delete (d) lines from line 1 to the matching start line. Then delete lines from the matching end line to the last line ($). You probably also want to delete the "Virtual Address" header line too. All that's left is what you want!

```
sed '1,/^ROUTING TABLE/d
     /^Virtual Address,/d
     /^GLOBAL STATS/,$d'
```

Comment: This made the most sense to me so you get the vote.

Answer (score 1):

The following *sed* command

```
      sed -n '/ROUTING/,/\[ B/{p}' filename
```

does what you wish: the *-n* suppresses the default behaviour which is to print every line, the expression between single quotes selects a range of lines, then prints them (this is the meaning of  *{p}*). The ranges to be selected are identified by means of matches (the initial and final one) delimited by separatrices, in my case I use the forward slash <kbd>/</kbd> as separatrix; the initial and final pattern match must be separated by a comma, and *\[* is used to stress the literal meaning of the square parenthesis, *i.e.* this is not a grammatical structure but instead it is a real opening square parenthesis which must be found.